# What is the best IDE for ionic app and its requirement

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to switch into Ionic app ( android ) but on net lot of idea is given. Please help me to choose best way to create the Ionic app,

Comment: This is opinionated and not useful in stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

There is no special IDE for Ionic but for intellisense and running the code you should use **VSCode** [Installation of ionic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_environment_setup.htm) may find above link and get the knoweldge of [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/) here.You may also go through the Ionic [Official website](https://ionicframework.com/docs/)  for more knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Sublime and atom text editor will do .There are several plugins you could use for angularJS like angularJS Snippets the could help you while writing code for angularJS

to start working on ionice you need to install npm ,cordova and also install android studio for the android sdk

here's the reference
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html

Another thing is that i think there's no such thing as best IDE because it may varies from different developers on how they deal with matters in their text editor

Tell me if this helped you :)